# Match a String with quotes inside quotes

Tags: java, matcher, quote

I'm trying to separate a String with comas with a Matcher, but when the String contains quotes inside it dosn't separate correctly, i have the following String:

```
String s = "\"\"\"Lili,Carl\"\"\",Jimenez,11,38";
```

This should divide this way:

- "Lili,Carl"
- Jimenez
- 11
- 38

I have tried it with this matcher:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]+").matcher(s);

       while (m.find()){
           System.out.println(m.group());
       }
```

But the result i get is this:

- ""
- "Lili,Carl"
- ""
- Jimenez
- 11
- 38

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Use a CSV parser?

Comment: Why not use a simple `string.split()` and split at the comma?

Comment: Because in case i want to add a , inside the quotes

Comment: Ok, that's a new requirement, which was not in the question before. Maybe you define all your requirements or you'll likely get inappropriate answers.

Comment: And why should it remove 2 of the 3 quotation marks? What if there are 6 quotation marks? Is it divided by 3 or subtracted 2?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i edite the question a little

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the matcher is not necessary, with this code:

```
String s = "\"Li,li\",Jimenez,11,38";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^,]+").matcher(s);

       while (m.find()){
           System.out.println(m.group());
       }
  }
```

the output is:

```
"Li
li"
Jimenez
11
38
```

If I understand that should be the output to the input S